# How to use marco to dynamically change color of row if there is same value in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

Could you please lead me in below task?

In excel sheet I want to make that if there is a same value in a column, I want to dynamically change the color of the row that includes the same value.
The important point is that, i want to change the color of the only row based on other column cell value.

Ex:
No | Patch number    |    Patch version

1        123456                6

2     123456                7

In above example, I only want to change the color of row of number 1. The condition is based on Patch version .

Thank you!

Comment: So you only want rows colored where patch number is the same and patch version is less than the maximum patch version for that patch number?

Comment: Select the cells then  *Home tab >> Conditional formatting >> highlight cells rules >> duplicate values*

Comment: @JerryJeremiah yes your understanding is totally right!

Comment: @TimWilliams I tried that but with that procedure, it colors both columns with duplicate value...

Answer (score 0):

For this example I entered the desired patch number in another sheet and named the cell 'PatchHighlight'

Then used this formula for conditional highlighting on rows 2 to 100

```
=$C2=PatchHighlight
```

The PatchHighlight cell could itself contain a formula, such as `=MAX(C:C)`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think this does what you want.  It can highlight any row where another row has the same value in A and a larger number in B.  The formula to use is:

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,"="&$A2,$B:$B,">"&$B2)>0
```

If you stick this formula in C2 it will display TRUE or FALSE depending on whether other rows have the same value in A and a larger number in B or not.  Then you could copy it down to all the other cells in C.

If you want to highlight rows using this you need to highlight row 2 and choose Conditional Formatting, choose New Rule, choose "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" and enter this formula along with the desired formatting.  Then you need to choose Conditional Formatting, choose Manage Rules and enter this formula into the Applies To field:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,0,0,COUNTA($A:$A),3)
```

This will make the conditional formatting apply to columns A, B and C of every row of data you have.  And if you add more data it will automatically highlight those rows too.

For more detailed instructions have a look at https://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/05/17/prevent-duplicates-using-dynamic-conditional-formatting-in-excel/ but use these formulas instead of the ones they suggest for finding duplicates.